# Protecting the custom ribbon in Excel 2007

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm creating a custom ribbon for a workbook in Excel 2007. If I open the Excel file as a zip file, then I can see the `customUI.xml` file that was created for these modifications to the ribbon to work.

What I would like to do is to protect the Excel file from users opening the file as a zip file and removing the `customUI.xml` file and thus being able to bypass the custom ribbon controls.
I would like to accomplish this without using password protection when opening the file in Excel. Users should be able to open and fill in information in the sheet without entering a password, but they should not have access to the workbook's zip structure content.

Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish this?

Edit: The solution is to use a VSTO solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent users from editing the excel file. If the user can edit the file, he can edit it in any way.

Comment: The user must edit the file and enter data. I just don't want him to access the default menu (Save, Save As etc.). Kind of like a dictator application, but I would like to have my menu overwriting the default menu, and not show up in the AddIn tab.
I was also thinking of checking the hashsum of the customUI.xml file to make sure it wasn't tampered, but I'm not sure how to do that in VBA.

Comment: I'm sure Excel doesn't allow that.